# Combinatorics (combinations problem)

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways are there to pick a group of $4$ people from $10$ people (each of a different height) and then pick a second group of $3$ other people such that all the people in the first group are taller than all the people in the second group? (Hint: Consider two  ways)

I try to illustrate it to sort the shortest to the tallest, then I found out four different cases. But my lecturers mean to use 2 ways, can anyone help me??

[image]

Comment: Do not vandalize your own questions.

Comment: i wan to delete my question already. can i?

Comment: No, people spent time and effort answering it.  Also, the question and its answers may be helpful to future users of this site.

Comment: What are you trying to do with my answer? It looks like vandalism.

Comment: @drhab It might be best to approve the edit, then flag it for moderator attention, and then roll it back.  That way there will be a record.

Comment: @TrevorWilson Thanks for the tip. However I allready rejected and saw that others had done that too. What exactly do you mean by 'roll it back' (I am Dutch)?. It is the first time that this happens to me.

Comment: @drhab That's okay; it's not terribly important.  What I meant is that on the "revisions" page (if you click "edited XX hours ago") you can go to a previous version and click "rollback", which causes the question to revert to that version, undoing any subsequent edits.

Comment: sorry, i made mistake. pls forgive me. i wont do it again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pick $7$ people from $10$, and let the $3$ shortest ones be called the second group. This can be done in $\binom{10}{7}$ ways.

**Remark:** The cases approach of the post does some double-counting. One can adjust it, by organizing by "shortest in the group of $4$," If the shortest in that group is to be say Person $6$, then we need to choose **three** from the $5$ tallest.

Comment: can u explain more? our method jz about 165 ways, and urs one is 120 ways..what make the difference between

Comment: The calculation you made is wrong, it does some double-counting of cases. In my expanded remark above, I give one way to fix that sort of idea to avoid double-counting.

Comment: will it the taught u have in the other replied answer is the same?

Comment: The answer by drhab is along the same lines as the procedure I sketched in the Remark, and gives full detail. The answer I gave in the main answer gives a very quick way of getting the count, and is based on a different idea (not cases).

Comment: You are welcome. Double-counting sometimes happens in subtle ways, and can be difficult to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Let's number the people by $1,\dots,10$ in order of length. So $1$
is the smallest. The shortest of the first group chosen must belong
to $\left\{ 4,5,6,7\right\} $. This because at least $3$ persons are
shorter and at least $3$ persons are taller.

If $4$ is the shortest of the first group then there are $\binom{6}{3}\times\binom{3}{3}=20$
possibilities.

If $5$ is the shortest of the first group then there are $\binom{5}{3}\times\binom{4}{3}=40$
possibilities.

If $6$ is the shortest of the first group then there are $\binom{4}{3}\times\binom{5}{3}=40$
possibilities.

If $7$ is the shortest of the first group then there are $\binom{3}{3}\times\binom{6}{3}=20$
possibilities.

The first factor corresponds with the first group (**where the smallest
is determined allready**) and second with the second group.

In total there are $120$ possibilities.

In your calculation there
are possibilities that are counted twice.